# Comparar dados de dois BD'S diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia pessoal,

**Tenho o seguinte cenario:**
BD1 de terceiros onde posso apenas realizar consultas.
Criei uma pagina web para exibição dos dados do BD1, no caso seria uma tabela onde tenho um campo com uma combobox que tenho algumas opções para serem selecionadas.

**Problema:**
Preciso salvar o estado da combobox de acordo com o ID da tabela para que toda vez que ela seja carregada ele mostre a informação que foi selecionada.

**Tentativa:**
Criei um BD2 local, para gravar as informações nesse caso ele grava o ID do BD1 e a opção selecionada da combobox, pensei em fazer um INNER JOIN entre os bancos mas não achei nada que possa me ajudar e também não sei ao certo se essa seria a melhor solução.

**Códigos:**

```
$q_db2 = $conn2->query("SELECT monitor.infos.iStatus, monitor.infos.iCliente FROM monitor.infos");

$data = array();   

while($rows2 = $q_db2->fetch_assoc()){

    $q_db1 = $conn->query("SELECT OS.OS, OS.DATA, OS.CONTRA, OS.TIPO, OS.EQUIPE, OS.TECNICO, OS.TECNICO_AUX1, OS.DTAGEN, OS.UF, EQ.NOME AS EQNOME, TP.NOME AS TPNOME, TC.NOME AS TCNOME, TCX.NOME AS TCXNOME 
    FROM dados.tva1710 AS OS 
    INNER JOIN dados.tva1800 AS EQ 
    ON EQ.CODIGO = OS.EQUIPE 
    INNER JOIN dados.at_os AS TP 
    ON TP.CODIGO = OS.TIPO 
    INNER JOIN dados.tva1900 AS TC 
    ON TC.CODIGO = OS.TECNICO 
    INNER JOIN dados.tva1900 AS TCX 
    ON TCX.CODIGO = OS.TECNICO_AUX1
    WHERE OS.DTAGEN != '0000-00-00' AND OS.DTAGEN > '2018-01-01' AND OS.UF = 'SP'");
    while($rows = $q_db1->fetch_assoc()){

       $arrayData = array();
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['OS']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows2['iCliente']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['CONTRA']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['TPNOME']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['EQNOME']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['TCNOME']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['TCXNOME']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows['DTAGEN']);
       $arrayData[] = utf8_encode($rows2['iStatus']);

       $data[] = $arrayData;         
 }  
}
 $results = array(
"sEcho" => 1,
"iTotalRecords" => count($data),
"iTotalDisplayRecords" => count($data),
"aaData" => $data);

echo json_encode($results, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)  ;
exit;
```

Tentei criar um where igualando os campo ID do BD1 com o campo ID do BD2 mas ele me retornou apenas os dados que foram gravados, logo não deu certo também.

```
 WHERE OS.DTAGEN != '0000-00-00' AND OS.DTAGEN > '2018-01-01' AND OS.UF = 'SP' AND OS.OS = '{$rows2['iCliente']}'");
```